# httparty GET request: "Request is missing header: `Authorization`

Tags: ruby, http-headers, unix-timestamp, httparty, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm working on a Rails app that makes a GET request to the Seamless.gov API to get the fields of a form. When I run the following `curl` command I'm able to the the JSON response. However, when I do it from rails I get error:

> { "error": true, "error_log": [ { "error_code": "missing_header",
>   "error_message": "Request is missing header: `Authorization`",
>   "error_description":
>   "{\"Host\":\"nycopp.seamlessdocs.com\",\"Connection\":\"close\",\"X-

Here is the code I created:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

module SeamlessGov
  class Form
    include HTTParty
    attr_accessor :form_id
    base_uri "https://nycopp.seamlessdocs.com/api"

    def initialize(id)
      @api_key = ENV['SEAMLESS_GOV_API_KEY']
      @signature = generate_signature
      @form_id = id
      @timestamp = Time.now.to_i
    end

    def relative_uri
      "/form/#{@form_id}/elements"
    end

    def create_form
      self.class.get(relative_uri, generate_headers)
    end

    private

    def generate_signature
      OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', ENV['SEAMLESS_GOV_SECRET'], "GET+#{relative_uri}+#{@timestamp}")
    end

    def generate_headers
      {
        "Authorization"  => "HMAC-SHA256 api_key='#{@api_key}' signature='#{@signature}'",
        "AuthDate" => "#{@timestamp}"
      }
    end
  end
end
```

In the controller I pass in the form id as follows:

```
def display_form
    @form = SeamlessGov::Form.new(ENV['FORM_ID']).create_form
end
```

Is the headers being pass wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue:

`self.class.get(relative_uri, headers: generate_headers)`